# Testing impact of kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us in Linux 4.18.20

Tags: linux, scheduler

I am writing a test in C in Linux to check the impact of kernel parameter of kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us. In my Linux system, by default they are setting as `kernel.sched_rt_period_us = 1000000 kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = 950000`
Here is my C code to do the test,

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

static volatile uint64_t counter = 0;
static struct timeval start_ts, end_ts;
static int quit_loop = 0;

void alarm_handler(int sig)
{
    uint64_t diff_us = 0;
    gettimeofday(&end_ts, NULL);
    diff_us = 1000000 * (end_ts.tv_sec - start_ts.tv_sec) +
              end_ts.tv_usec - start_ts.tv_usec;
    printf("Counter = %ld in %ld useconds\n", counter, diff_us);
    quit_loop = 1;
    return;
}

int start_main_process(int sec)
{
    struct sched_param schedp;

    schedp.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO);
    if (sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_FIFO, &schedp) == -1) {
        perror("error: Failed to set the thread priority");
        return -1;
    }
    signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler); // Register signal handler
    alarm(sec);                        // Scheduled alarm after 2 seconds
    gettimeofday(&start_ts, NULL);

    while(quit_loop == 0) {
        counter ++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int ret = 0;
    int sec = 3;

    if (argc > 1) {
        sec = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    start_main_process(sec);
    return ret;
}
```

It sets a timer (e.g. 6 seconds) to interrupt the counting loop and report the counter during that period.
The process is set to use SCHED_FIFO with priority 99, to make sure it is a highest priority process.
Then, I ran the itin an isolated CPU to check the outputs with different settings of kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us, below is the testing results.

```
kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = 100000
Counter = 1022833830 in 6000009 useconds

kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = 200000
Counter = 2051812152 in 6000007 useconds

kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = 400000
Counter = 2565972333 in 6000005 useconds

kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = 800000
Counter = 2559221709 in 6000006 useconds

kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = 950000
Counter = 2563922373 in 6000005 useconds
```

The results showed that counter is NOT linear to the setting of sched_rt_runtime_us!
BTW, I also created a normal process busy looping in that isolated CPU, which is used as non-rt workload in background. Interrupt affinity is also adjusted to move non-critical interrupts to other CPUs.
Did I missed anything or something wrong in my testing ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to set "no turbo" in /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate?

```
cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate
sudo su
echo 1 > no_turbo
```

This may help.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I am running my test in a Linux VM, so no such file in sysfs. Also intel_pstate=disable is added into the kernel command line.

Comment: Oh, ok. Anyway your results could be influenced by non fixed frequency in the processor. Are you sure that during your test the processor has the same frequency during all time? I've done something similar during one of my university course. [link](http://retis.sssup.it/luca/CBSD/kvm_experiments.txt) try to read this, may help.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the kernel.sched_rt_period_us is the *total* number shared by a group of CPUs.

For example, in my 8vCPU VM configuration, CPU4-7 are isolated for running specific processes. So the kernel.sched_rt_period_us should be evenly divided among these 4 isolated CPUs, which means kernel.sched_rt_period_us/4 = 250000 is 100% CPU quota for each CPU in the isolated group.

Setting kernel.sched_rt_period_us to 250000 makes the SCHED_FIFO process take all of the CPU. Accordingly, 25000 means 10% CPU usage for the CPU, 50000 means 20%, etc.

This is also validated when CPU6 and CPU7 are isolated, in this case, 500000 can make the CPU to be 100% used by SCHED_FIFO process, 250000 makes 50% CPU usage.

Since these two kernel parameters are global ones, which means if the SCHED_FIFO process is put into the CPU0-5, 1000000/6 = 160000 should be the 100% quota for each CPU, 80000 makes 50% CPU usage, I also validated this.